# Los estilos de tailwind no cargan en mi app de laravel una vez que la subi con la funcion de apps de digitalocean

Tags: css, laravel

Subi un pequeño proyecto escolar con la funcion de apps de digital ocean, cuando lo pruebo en local todo funciona correctamente, pero al subir el proyecto los estilos no me cargan, alguien sabe como puedo solucionar esto? aqui dejo una captura al inspeccionar mi sitio web, me aparece que se bloquearon los archivos css y js por alguna razon que desconozco, si alguien quiere inspeccionar la pagina se mira el dominio en la imagen que comparti

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]